# Are there examples of municipal mayors or alderman/alderwomen or city counsilors who became Federal senators in the US?

Tags: united-states, congress

Have any representatives at an urban/municipal level gone on to Federal politics?

Comment: Pretty much everyone starts at some lower level, first.  Are you referring to people directly getting elected as Senator when running as a current municipal office-holder, or anyone who used to be, at any previous time, a County Executive, Mayor, city or county councilor?

Comment: Bernie Sanders was mayor of Burlington, VT, before he became a US Senator, but he was also a US Congressman in between. Does that count?

Comment: Headline text asks specifically about Senators, while the body just references "Federal politics". Can you clarify which you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, below are some examples of incumbent Senators who had been mayor, county executive or a state legislator before becoming a Senator.

- Senators who were previously mayors

  - [Dianne Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dianne_Feinstein) was formerly Mayor of San Francisco
  - [Bob Corker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Corker) was formerly Mayor of Chattanooga
  - [Cory Booker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cory_Booker) was Mayor of Newark
  - [Bernie Sanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernie_Sanders) was Mayor of Burlington before becoming a Representative
- or county executives

  - [Mitch McConnell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitch_McConnell) was formerly Judge/Executive of Jefferson County
  - [Chris Coons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Coons) was formerly County Executive of New Castle County
- or in state legislatures

  - [Patty Murray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patty_Murray) served in the Washington Senate
  - [Lisa Murkowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisa_Murkowski) was a member of the Alaska House of Representatives.
  - [Deb Fischer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_Fischer) was in the Nebraska Legislature
  - [Joni Ernst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joni_Ernst) was in the Iowa Senate

Comment: Other ex-mayors include Bernie Sanders (I-VT, previously Mayor of Burlington) and Cory Booker (D-NJ, previously Mayor of Newark). Other former state legislators include a little-known guy called Barack Obama. There are many, many other examples in US history, IMO this question should be closed as too broad.